# What to do with baseboard for this basement with concrete box?

Tags: concrete, basement, hardwood-floor, trim, baseboard

This is in my basement and I plan to install wood flooring.
But this is what in the bottom of the wall:

[image]

It is like a box 2x2.

Previously I had baseboard on top of the concrete box running along the wall. BUT it was ugly.

Does anyone have a better idea what to do or cover this?

Maybe I can just paint it as same as the wall and run some 1x2 on top??!

**UPDATE 1**

The wall looks like this:

```
|
|
|
|
--
  |
--------------------
```

Comment: Can you re-do that photo and get something that gives a lot better sense of what the lower wall corner looks like. The current photo gives no help at all.

Comment: I added UPDATE 1. Basically its a 2x2" box running along bottom of wall.

Comment: Your diagram is a 100% improvement. Instead of calling that a "box" I think of it more as a "curbing".

Answer (score 1):

Some tile would look good. You can attach the tile easily with some Power Grab or other construction adhesive. Once the tile dries you can grout it and then seal it.

Comment: I am thinking about just glueing plywood and making it an official curb from the wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put down a wood floor would it make sense to finish the basement walls that would enhance the whole basement. The walls could be insulated then finished any way you desire. This would yield a larger sq. ft. home that you could use as a finished game room or whatever .

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should add some detail about how this could solve the problem that the OP is dealing with the curbing at the bottom of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was aimed directly at your desire to simply do something with the curbs. However, you also stated that you planned on installing a wood floor. Here is a side view drawing of how you can achieve both issues at once. First, attach a side board on the top of the curbing (Make sure it's level all the way across) Nail it to the concrete wall with cut nails or Tapcon screws. Cut out joists that will sit snugly against the curbing and allow a small space between the bottom of the joist and the existing floor (in case of a basement leak). Nail/screw the joists to the side plates on each end. I would do one joist on each end of the room and then run a string across the top of it to keep the others level. You can adjust the height on each end of the other joists by chiseling out a little more wood from your notches or adding shims. Install 3/4 T&G plywood with liquid nails and screws and then whatever flooring you desire.
[image: Wood Floor Diagram]

And for doorway issues this would be a good option...

[image: Doorway Diagram]

Comment: Well adding a step and increase floor level is a definitely no. Thanks for the idea though.